# Embedding external applications into fxml

Tags: java, fxml

I am trying to start an external application (java swing) and them display the java window within another java application. I can start at external application pretty easily but I can't seem to see a way of displaying it with something like a javafx pane.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do so only if the other app is embedded into your code that you have it's source code now you can open it inside your app in the case of `swing` `javafx` you can open them in the same app not a big deal
 I hope this might help you